# Replacing a shorted IGBT

Tags: diodes, igbt

**Introduction to the problem**

While I'm using my treadmill, the house fuse breaker went down (Shorted). After I lifted up the fuse breaker & tried to use the treadmill, it showed me Err 02.

**My steps to figure out the problem**

I searched & watched a video on YouTube regards this error, I followed the steps & measured the IGBTs of the treadmill board.

[Repair Treadmill Error Code E02 | Control Board Faulty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iKytvRF1i4)

One of the IGBTs readings are 0.00 (Not 0L) on the multimeter using diode mode test, unlike the other 2 IGBTs that I measured and their reading are between 0.370 & 0.423 volts

**My questions**

1- Did the shorted IGBT behind the house fuse being shorted or it was the opposite?

2- I found online a IGBT (G40N60 IGBT 600V – 70A), And the one on the board is (G40N60 UFD C13AK), is this a right replacement?

3- What's the best practice to make sure that the problem comes only from this shorted IGBT & there're no more faulty elements? To avoid the new one being shorted too.

P.S: I'm newbie to electronics world.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: specify the units of the reading you got for better clarity, is it Volts?

Comment: @Juan Thank you, I corrected the question. The readings are 0.370v & 0.423v . I tested using the diode mode in the multimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- All I can say is that you had a large current that caused the fuse to melt, without any extra info that is all I can say. That current while it lasted could damage other stuff.

2.- You are calling it a diode, but those are both IGBTs, they require a signal to be controlled and have 3 terminals, unlike a diode that only has 2(among other differences) also specify the units of the reading you got, is that voltage?

3.- from the datasheet you showed, some components are not even diodes to begin with, the only way is to deeply understand how the circuit works and make sure every component is working well.

Comment: Thank you, I edited & corrected the question. The readings are 0.370v & 0.423v. How to find out the max Amperage of the diode on my electrical board?